# Matlab plots directly inside c++ GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface, matlab

I'm using matlab compiler to generate c++ shared library from my m files.
Is it possible to display matlab plots directly inside c++ GUI (not in a separate window) ?

Comment: interesting question although I'm afraid the answer might be no: all ui stuff in matlab is done with java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found easy solution. If you are using windows you could just setparent to matlab window. 
something like this.

```
HWND h = FindWindow(L"SunAwtFrame", L"Figure 1");

void MatlabViewerHack::EmbedMatlabPlot(HWND h)
{
   SetWindowPos(h,NULL,rect.left(), rect.top(), rect.width(), rect.height(),0);
   SetWindowLong(h, GWL_STYLE,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE);
   SetParent(h, parent_widget);             //dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(parent())->winId()

   //updating ui_state, windows xp, window 7
   SendMessage(h, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
   SendMessage(parent_widget, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
   SendMessage(h, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
   SendMessage(parent_widget, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);

   current_window = h;
}
```

Comment: you should mark this as the answer. I just used it to embed a matlab surface plot in a WPF app and it works great.

Comment: Hi @Heorhiy ! Is it possible to do the same with wpf? I need to display matlab plots inside my wpf application(not in a separate window). Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB uses [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/), which is built on Java/Swing for their user interface. Embeddable figures have not been available for [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) as well. Therefore I think, according to *stijn*, there are no embeddable plots. I would love to be proven wrong.